# Looping through a list with a custom counter

Tags: python

I have a list of directories in called `dirs`.

I also have a custom counter function called `snake` which uses the following syntax.

```
snake(low, high, x)
```

An example of its usage would be

```
[snake(1,3,x) for x in range(8)]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

`dirs` contains multiple identical directories.  For example

```
[/my/path/one/, /my/path/one/, /my/path/one/, /my/path/one/, 
 /my/path/two/, /my/path/two/, /my/path/two/]
```

I'd like to use snake to create a variable with a set of indices associated with `dirs` where the snake pattern resets when a new directory name is encountered in the list. Something like:

```
ind = [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure python:

```
def snake(low, high):
    return itertools.cycle(itertools.chain(
        range(low, high + 1),
        range(high, low - 1, -1)))
```

Usage:

```
>>> list(itertools.islice(snake(1, 3), 8))
[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

Let's now write a shy snake which panics and resets the generator when it encounters a new item:

```
def shy_snake(low, high, iterable):
    """d-d-doesss s-s-sssenpai noticesss me?"""
    prev = None
    for x in iterable:
        if x != prev:
            prev = x
            snake_it = snake(low, high)
        yield next(snake_it)
```

Actually, we can write this a bit more generically, to work with any sequence generator:

```
def shy(seq_func, iterable):
    prev = None
    for x in iterable:
        if x != prev:
            prev = x
            it = seq_func()
        yield next(it)

def shy_snake(low, high, iterable):
    """d-d-doesss s-s-sssenpai noticesss me?"""
    return shy(lambda: snake(low, high), iterable)
```

Testing:

```
>>> dirs = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
>>> list(shy_snake(1, 3, dirs))
[1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Very interesting ... how does one turn a list of `strings` in `dirs` into the `iterable` required by `shy_snake`?

Comment: The nice thing about the `!=` operator is that it works with both integers and strings. :) You can plug `dirs` straight into there.

Comment: Cool .. I need to play with this and get my mind around it.  This is WAY simpler than `snake` function I'd be using previously which was more mathematical in nature.

Comment: oh no ... I just realized my application is limited to python2.7 because I need to use Jython.

Comment: Itertools and the star expressions in snake

Comment: I've edited `snake` to work with Python 2.7. Make sure you're importing itertools.